# missing horizontal scrollbar when using direction rtl

Tags: html, css

I have 3 links whose combined width totals 690px. If i resize the browser window to be smaller than this width horizontal scrollbars appear, which is what i want.

If i add direction:rtl to the container no horizontal scrollbars appear

```
<div class="container">
   <div><a id="paymentsLink" href="#self">Payments</a></div>    
   <div><a id="inquiriesLink" href="#self">Inquiries</a></div>
   <div><a id="tradeLink" href="#self">Trade</a></div>
</div>
```

Please see the following fiddle's and resize html area to be smaller than 690px

**LTR** : Scrollbars appearing and all ok - http://jsfiddle.net/grimmus/hD438/8/

**RTL** : No scrollbars - http://jsfiddle.net/grimmus/hD438/9/

I am wondering why no scrollbar is appearing when direction:rtl is added to the container ?

Answer (score 1):

I thought you may need to put the "direction:rtl " in body{}

```
body {margin:0; direction:rtl;}
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps alright. I thought i could place anywhere in the page.

Comment: that's right you can put it anywhere the issue not in direction the issue in the overflow it will work if you set to "auto" check http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Comment: Thanks but overflow:auto is placing a scrollbar on the container element when i need it on the whole page.

Comment: You don't need put overflow:auto anymore otherwise you need to read more about this properties :) You are welcome